# Iterate from controls inside data template - windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, datatemplate

I have a MultiselectList Control (from SL toolkit) in which i have data template with a check box. This is the xaml code i have:

```
<toolkit:MultiselectList x:Name="BankMultiSelectList" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomItemTemplate}"/>
```

and the data template:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomItemTemplate">
        <CheckBox x:Name="BankCheckBox" Content="{Binding Path=Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

The binding is becoming with members in the bank class which is the following:

```
public class Bank
{
    public Bank() { }

    public Bank(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public List<Bank> GetBanks()
    {
        return new List<Bank>()
        {
            new Bank("Eurobank"),
            new Bank("Millennium Bank"),
            new Bank("Attica Bank"),
            new Bank("Ταχυδρομικό Ταμιευτήριο"),
            new Bank("Alpha Bank"),
            new Bank("Τραπεζα Κύπρου"),
            new Bank("Hellenic Bank"),
            new Bank("Probank"),
            new Bank("FBBank"),
            new Bank("CitiBank"),
            new Bank("Τραπεζα Πειραιώς"),
            new Bank("HSBC Bank"),
            new Bank("Εθνική Τράπεζα"),
            new Bank("Εμπορική Τράπεζα"),
            new Bank("Proton Bank"),
            new Bank("Αγροτική Τράπεζα"),
            new Bank("Γενική Τράπεζα"),
            new Bank("Tbank"),
            new Bank("Marfin Egnatia Bank"),
        };
    }
}
```

In the page load i i fill the ItemsSource of MultiselectList (called BankMultiSelectList) with data from the bank class:

```
Bank bank = new Bank();
BankMultiSelectList.ItemsSource = bank.GetBanks();
```

That creates a page with some checkboxes with their names bind from the class method. I want to create a "select all" button in application bar to select all checkboxes at once when i press. How can i iterate through all the checkbox controls of the page in order to, let's say, set their IsChecked property to true? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Looking at your other questions, you commented some answers as helpful. Please also mark them as answers. That's polite and gives you some reputation, too.

Comment: Hello @ShegitBrahm and thanks for your suggestion. I marked any answer that was helpful to me in this post but also in previous posts i had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* iterate over the elements in the UI and set their checked state. But a *much* better way to do this would be to set the state of your model and let the bindings do the work of updating the UI for your.

1. Modify your `Bank` class to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, specifically on the `IsSelected` property.
2. Iterate over all of the instances of this class and set `IsSelected=true`

... and you're done!

Comment: Hello ColinE. Thanks for your answer. Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged interface in my Bank class and using foreach loop to iterate through Bank items inside BankMultiSelectList.ItemsSource solved my problem.